# React Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I use one component 2 times. When it call first time evering is good but when I call second time (move to different component through the react router) I have exception `Uncaught ReferenceError: titleStyle is not defined`. In console I see the problem in this line: `_react2.default.createElement("h2", { style: titleStyle },this.props.title,":")`
What I did wrong?

**TitleWithAddButton.jsx** (the component with problem)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'

export default class TitleWithAddButton extends React.Component{
 render(){
    let titleStyle = {
        width:"50%"
    };

     var button = {
         width: "10%",
         float: "right"
     };

    return (
        <div className="title-with-add-button">
            <div>
                <Link to="/carwashAdd"><button type="button" className="btn btn-success" style={button}>Add</button></Link>
            </div>
            <h2 style={titleStyle}>{this.props.title}:</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**CarWashPage.jsx** (the first time componen is call from it)

```
import React from 'react';
import TitleWithAddButton from './TitleWithAddButton.jsx';
import AllCarWashTable from './carwash/AllCarWashTable.jsx'

export default class CarWashPage extends React.Component{

render(){
    var carWashPageStyle = {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10
    }

    return (
       <div style={carWashPageStyle}> 
            <TitleWithAddButton title="All carwash"/>
            <AllCarWashTable/>
       </div>    
    )
}
}
```

**AddCarWashPage.jsx** (second time component is call from here)

```
import React from 'react';
import Title from './../Title.jsx'

export default class AddCarWashPage extends React.Component{

render(){
    var addCarWashPage = {
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10
    }

    return (
        <div style={addCarWashPage}>
            <Title title="Add CarWash"/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: can you add the code for your `Title.jsx` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to include `TitleWithAddButton` in the file `AddCarWashPage.jsx` where your second call happens, but included `import Title from './../Title.jsx'` instead.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It might be a different module, plus this is a `ReferenceError` inside the component

Comment: hm, fair enough. Let's see what he says, I will delete my answer if the guess wasn't correct.

Comment: Wait, you actually may be right, as the OP says they call it the second time inside `AddCarWashPage`. I'd say, if it is the case, to flag as a typo.

Comment: Also see that `AddCarWashPage.jsx` in his file structure would naturally be 1 level deeper than `AddCarWash.jsx` which is exactly on the same level / same package with the supposed `Title.jsx` and thus `TitleWithAddButton.jsx`. Thanks for the suggestion, how can I flag the question as typo?

Comment: There's a button under the question that says 'flag'. Go to 'should be closed', then 'off-topic', finally 'no reproduce or typo'.

Comment: @EugenePodoliako you're welcome. You can also accept the answer if it solved your problem.